# Get warnings from PMD with Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, warnings, jenkins-pipeline, pmd

How get number of warnings from PMD with Jenkins Pipeline?.
I have tried but can not find a way to fix this

Comment: You should look at https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md#plugin-developer-guide The pmd plugin is not supported yet

Comment: @Beuj: PMD plugin is already supported, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Code Analysis block stage:

```
stage('CAT') {

    step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.checkstyle.CheckStylePublisher', checkstyle: '**/target/checkstyle-result.xml'])

    step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.pmd.PmdPublisher', checkstyle: '**/target/pmd.xml'])

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle PMD in Jenkinfile (PHP project):

```
stage('PMD') {
    steps {
        sh 'vendor/bin/phpmd . xml build/phpmd.xml --reportfile build/logs/pmd.xml --exclude vendor/ || exit 0'
        pmd canRunOnFailed: true, pattern: 'build/logs/pmd.xml'
    }
}
```

Reference links

- https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/
- https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pmd/